# Can I load a figure stored as an HTML file (generated using Plotly’s python library) within Dash?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I’ve used Plotly’s Python library, but I’m a newbie to Dash.
Here’s my use case:

We have a Wordpress site that has a section called “dashboard”. The site has multiple users and we’d like to show different charts/dash apps to each user based on only their data.

So far, I’ve succeeded in embedding the HTML generated using Plotly’s library within Wordpress. This is sufficient but not very aesthetically pleasing. What I want to do next is when a user clicks on “dashboard”, they’d be directed to a dash app, which will be running as a docker container on, say, AWS ECS. One container for each customer.

So, here’s the main question: We generate charts for each user separately and store them on S3 at the moment. So when my dash container is running, is there a way for me to load a particular chart (HTML) and embed that into my Dash app?

The reason I’m asking this is - the charts use data from a MySQL database and if dash requires a constant connection to the data source to render the charts, that’d be terribly slow.

Comment: You could store your data as JSON in S3 and parse it in dash - Boto3 helps you to interact with AWS services

Comment: is there a way to load graph stored as JSON in Dash? Could you point me to the API reference if possible?

Comment: You can just parse your json in python and use it as data input. `json.load()`

Comment: I know how to parse json in python, I'm also aware of boto3. I'm asking if there's a way to use a graph stored as JSON or HTML in Dash?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67380802/1256347

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a pretty simple solution for this use case:

Plotly supports exporting a Figure object as JSON.

> `fig.to_json()`

Dump this into a file and store onto the disk or S3.

You can regenerate the original figure object from the JSON like so:

```
import plotly.io as pio

with open('path_of_fig_stored_as_json', 'r') as f:
    fig = pio.from_json(f.read())
```