# After saving a plotly figure to html file, can you re-read it later as a figure?

Tags: python, html, plotly, figure

I'd like to edit the data, probably adding more traces to the graph.
I've found a way to display the html file as a graph, but not to edit it.

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(filename='file_name.html')
```

Answer (score 11):

Normally [Plotly JSON](https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/#converting-graph-objects-to-dictionaries-and-json) should be used for (de)serialisation of charts (e.g. [`figure.write_json`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.html#plotly.basedatatypes.BaseFigure.write_json) and [`plotly.read_json`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.io.read_json.html#plotly.io.read_json)). However, if you only have the HTML representation of the chart, the same Plotly JSON is fed to `plotly.js` there, and it can be extracted.

For the sake of demonstration only. `plotly==5.1.0` used.

```py
import json
import re

import plotly.express


def write():
    fig = plotly.express.bar(y=[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34])
    fig.write_html('plot.html', full_html=True)
    fig.write_json('plot.json')


def read_from_json():
    return plotly.io.read_json('plot.json')


def read_from_html():
    with open('plot.html') as f:
        html = f.read()
    call_arg_str = re.findall(r'Plotly\.newPlot\((.*)\)', html[-2**16:])[0]
    call_args = json.loads(f'[{call_arg_str}]')
    plotly_json = {'data': call_args[1], 'layout': call_args[2]}    
    return plotly.io.from_json(json.dumps(plotly_json))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    write()
    read_from_json()
    read_from_html()
```

Comment: getting JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1) when executing the above without any changes on read_from_html . Any ideas?

Comment: found  call_arg_str = re.findall(r'Plotly\.newPlot\((.*)\)', html[-2**16:])[0] on another web site . Seems to work with that change

Comment: Traced problem to the index of item found by re.findall. Actually call_arg_str = re.findall(r'Plotly\.newPlot\((.*)\)', html)[1] works  so you may have to iterate on index of items to find one that works as valid call_arg_str for the json.loads function

Comment: `html[-2**16:]` is an assumption that the chart data is in the bottom 64 KiB of the page produced by `write_html` with `full_html=True`. The top of the page contains embedded Plotly.js which is pointless to parse. Unless `plotly.express` changed the output this is optimal.

Comment: What about `call_arg_str = re.findall(r'Plotly\.newPlot\((.*)\)', html)[-1]` assuming that the last appearance of `Plotly.newPlot(` will be followed by the data? It works for me.  `html[-2**16:]` is not universal.